# Meshing Micro-Structure in Abaqus/CAE

Tags: abaqus

I have created a part constituting a microstructure of different volume fractions of the phases and want to mesh the whole part, but Abaqus shows me the following error.

[image]

And below is my entire part with two phases: matrix (cube) and inclusions (spheres).
[image]

One possible reason I see is the fact that the phases are being represented as really tiny solid deformable spheres (~0.16). In contrast, the part as a whole (~10) is not that small, so Abaqus cannot insert boundary triangles efficiently. Therefore, I used 'tet' mesh (default-algorithm), technique 'free' (it was only permitted for my part) with the global seed of 0.1.

What should I do? Should is change my mesh control from 'tet' to something else, 'tet' was the easiest to use in my case, though.

Any suggestion will help me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: From my experience, Abaqus meshing tool is not very sophisticated for problems of such type (when you need to have not regular mesh with a big difference between small and big elements). Of course, you can just choose a very small global seed size (~0.04) but you will get a huge model. As a general rule, try to decrease your ROI to the minimum, cause now it seems quite possible to take only part of this cube.


In a similar problem, I've used Hypermesh software as it is better to handle complex meshing and allows you to do some smart re-meshing until you are satisfied.

Comment: @RomanZhuravlev, thanks for the valuable suggestions. One off-topic question: is there any way to render the sphere the BCC and cube the HCP structures? I know the property only for bulk material, i.e., the entire system (Ti-8Mn alloy). So how do I assign the alpha phase and beta phase properties to spheres and cubes? I tried using the Lever rule of the phase diagrams to get the composition (wt.% Mn) of alpha and beta phase, but this gives me very varied wt. % Mn, data of which I don't have.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the question (probably because the subject is unknown to me). BCC/HCP - you are speaking about packing? What do you mean under "to render structures"?

Comment: @RomanZhuravlev Yes, I am talking of packing, is there any way to assign different packing to the spheres and cube? These two phases are made of the same alloy (Ti-8Mn alloy). The only difference is that one is an alpha phase (HCP) while the other beta phase (BCC); how do I incorporate this fact while defining their material properties?

Comment: You want to have two phases or to model the phase transition? In the first case it is more or less straightforward (choose your geometry/cells --> assign material); in the second, it is not so obvious, and I would suggest you to do a literature review on the subject.